# switch_root makes read only ROOT read/write?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm making edits to an init script that is a part of an initrd and I cannot figure out why switch_root changes the /dev/loop0 mounted at /root, which has the root filesystem, from "read only" mode to "read write". I'm modifying a Debian distro for a "Murphy compatible update" implementation which checks the md5 sum of the root image on every boot and I can't do this implementation if the root is read write as the image changes every boot. Is there some flag I can send to switch_root that can keep /dev/loop0 from making it read write? I know for a certainty that the mount is ro up until the switch_root is called.

Comment: Are you using the busybox switch_root implementation? the util-linux switch_root? Some other one?

Comment: Not really sure this is a bash question, by the way -- switch_root does not ship with, is not provided by, is usable independently of, and is otherwise not part of bash.

Comment: Also, I suggest checking whether `mount --move . /` in your chroot behaves the same way -- as it's basically a big chunk of what switch_root does (at least, reading the busybox implementation).

Comment: ...not just the busybox implementation; went through https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/switch_root.c, and it does the same thing.

Comment: Charles, it is the busybox implementation of switch_root.

Comment: Oh, so does that mean it's normal behavior? I'll try the command you suggest and let you know how that goes. Sorry for the misleading tag, was unintentional; wasn't sure what tags might be necessary.

Comment: By "same thing", I meant `mount --move . /`, not the ro->rw; I haven't verified (or found any direct basis) for that behavior.

Comment: Ah. Well `mount --move . /` didn't change it to rw either. Hmm... Is it possible it's being remounted by something on booting of the OS AFTER `switch_root`? What might that be?

Comment: I didn't mention it explicitly before, but this is a Debian distro.

Comment: That's what I would think more likely, yes; you could verify it by providing your own init to invoke after the switch. Unfortunately, tracking down the relevant what and where it's happening is probably a bit out-of-scope.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks for your help on this question, Charles. Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Not offhand. Been a while since I've poked at Debian's early boot process.